# How to make an asynchronous search (client call) to AWS Elasticsearch (7.10) over ESDomain host

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, aws-sdk-nodejs, opensearch

Asynchronous Search is available in AWS Elasticsearch starting with version:  7.10.  According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/supported-operations.html#version_7_10) operation `/_opendistro/_asynchronous_search`
is supported.  However, is there a client/an example that shows how to call this operation?

elasticsearch client, opensearch-js client do have `.search` method I could not locate or figure out how to make a call to cluster for _`asynchronous_search` operation.  All I have is ES domain url.  I can  make a client call to search but cannot locate or figure out how to do an `_asynchronous_search`

Please help.
Cluster AWS Elasticsearch 7.10

Answer (score 0):

It's an OS-specific feature, ES has a [different one](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/async-search.html) called `_async_search` which did not make it into OS.

Look [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/asynchronous-search.html) for an example on how to use this in OS.

Comment: tried the example and excepting gist is **index_not_found_exception**, not sure why "_plugins" is being treated as index name

Comment: I think you should try with `index-name/_plugins/_asynchronous_search` instead of just `/_plugins/_asynchronous_search`

Comment: Yes, slide #31 [here]https://pages.awscloud.com/rs/112-TZM-766/images/AWS-reInvent-2021-Recap-Presentation-Deck-6_Analytics.pdf

Comment: That slide is wrong, you should look at the official documentation instead of marketing material